# Configuration File for SSRS reports

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a variable in my SSRS reports, that I want to change after deployment, like we change app.config values for a windows application or web.config values for a web application. is this possible in SSRS reports? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can keep that variable value in database table.